# why Dictionary<string,object> null values loaded to object?

Tags: c#

I am using `Dictionary<string,object>` and loaded the data to `Gridview`, but null values show `<Object><Object>;`

```
public jsonresult getdata()
{
    sqlconnection con =new sqlconnection("");
    sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand("select * from table",con);
    var retObject=new List<dynamic>();
    using(Var datareader=cmd.excutereader())
    {
        while (datareader.read())
        {
            var datarow=new expandoObject()as IDictionary<string,Object>;
            for(var fieldcount=0;fieldcount<datareader.fieldcount,fieldcount++)
            datarow.add(datareader.Getname(fieldcount),datareader[fieldcount]);
            retObject.Add((ExpandoObject)datarow);

        }
    }
    return json(retObject);

}
```

> when load grid view null values are showing [object Object] on
>   change event in dropdownlist bind the data to gridview.But null values
>   in grid view it showing [object Object] remaining values are comming
>   perfectly

Comment: No offense, but could you get someone to rephrase that last paragraph? I frankly have no idea what's that supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible that `datareader[fieldcount]` is not null but `DBNull.Value`, compare the object with it and set real null value:

```
for(var fieldcount=0;fieldcount<datareader.fieldcount,fieldcount++)
{
    var value = datareader[fieldcount];
    datarow.add(datareader.Getname(fieldcount), value == DBNull.Value?null:value);
}
```